# *ngIf in ion-option in ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am using `ion-select` in ionic2. Below is my code:

```
       <ion-item>
            <ion-label>System Size:</ion-label>
            <ion-select [(ngModel)]="quoteDetailsUpdate.system_size" name="system">
                <ion-option value="1.5"> 1.5K </ion-option>
                <ion-option value="2"> 2K </ion-option>
                <ion-option value="3"> 3K </ion-option>
            </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
```

I want if the system size is between 1.5 and 2 then it should get selected the value 1.5K. Such if the value is 1.75 then it should get select the option 1.5K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should this change only affect the view? If that's the case, you can use a different property from your component like this:

```
public auxSystemSize: number;

...

constructor(...) {
    if(this.quoteDetailsUpdate.system_size > 1.5 && quoteDetailsUpdate.system_size < 2) {
        this.auxSystemSize = 1.5;
    } else {
        this.auxSystemSize = this.quoteDetailsUpdate.system_size;
    }
}
```

And then use that `auxSystemSize` in the view

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>System Size:</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="auxSystemSize" name="system">
        <ion-option value="1.5"> 1.5K </ion-option>
        <ion-option value="2"> 2K </ion-option>
        <ion-option value="3"> 3K </ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

This way the `quoteDetailsUpdate.system_size` property will keep its original value. Please notice that when submitting the form, you'll need to assign the value of the `auxSystemSize` back to the model (if you need to).